# Functional programming idiom for applying a series of void functions to a single value

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, vavr

Given a value `foo` and a `Stream` of `Consumer<Foo>` void functions, what's the most concise way to apply each function to the value? Right now I have

```
consumers.forEach(c -> c.accept(foo));
```

which isn't terrible, but I suspect there might be some way to turn this inside out and do it with just method references (no explicit lambda). Possibly something with a singleton list and `zip()`?

I'd be happy with a straight Java 8 answer, or [Vavr](http://vavr.io), or Scala.

(Note that this is not a fold, or at least not the usual `foldLeft`/`foldRight` application; if there were return values, I'd be discarding them, not iterating on them.)

Comment: Is *concatenating* via [`Consumer#andThen(Consumer after)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#andThen-java.util.function.Consumer-) a valid option?

Comment: Interesting question but in Java there is nothing as simple, concise, or performant in typical VMs, than what you already have.

Comment: `forEach` and void functions aren't used in functional idioms ... you're looking for something that doesn't exist

Comment: @naomik OK, pretend it's `functions.map(f -> f.apply(foo))` if you find that less nonexistent.

Comment: @naomik And consider the IO monad.

Comment: @DavidMoles `map` will build a new collection, which can be sent to another function;  `forEach` does not have a return value and therefore cannot be composed – `forEach` and void functions are not functional

Comment: @naomik I know what `map` does.

Comment: so then you’ll stop comparing it to `forEach` as some sort of equivalent?

Comment: @naomik The functionality of `map()` is a strict superset of `forEach()`. I would be happy with a solution that uses `map()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real concern here is that methods which return `void` are a code smell.  Why couldn't they return something useful, or at least carry out their side-effect and then return the original value, which allows for better chaining.  I think that would be a preferable approach, but short of that, I think the forEach approach is ok.

Comment: Would that make the code more concise? Say I (somewhere else, so it doesn't count against the concision) wrapped each `Consumer<Foo>` as a `Function<Foo, Foo>`: `Stream<Function<Foo, Foo>> functions = consumers.map(c -> (f) -> { c.accept(f); return f; });` — what would be the concise way to chain those?

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce your consumers by means of the `Consumer.andThen` method and then apply the resulting consumer to the `foo` argument:

```
consumers.reduce(Consumer::andThen).ifPresent(c -> c.accept(foo));
```

But there's no difference between this approach and yours, and yours' is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala you should be able to do

```
consumers.foreach(_.accept(foo));
```

Comment: That's exactly what the OP _did_, it's right there in the question.

Comment: It's not exactly the same. It compiles to the same bytecode but using different syntax. I'm not saying this is revolutionary but David asked for the way to do it in a more concise way and this is shorter, isn't it?

Comment: True enough, but if you are really trying to achieve concise Scala you would use `foreach` (`forEach` isn't Scala) and you'd drop the semicolon `;` (Scala isn't Java). Even after that, if we were playing a round of [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf), I'd still have you beat by 2 strokes: `for(c<-consumers)c.accept(foo)`

Comment: Yeah. I could get a bit closer with `consumers.foreach(_ accept foo)`. Still one character behind :). `consumers foreach _ accept foo` probably won't work :).

Comment: The reason I suggested I'd take a Scala solution is that it's usually straightforward to translate from Scala to Vavr, and there are probably more Scala programmers on here than (good) functional Java programmers. This answer is "more concise," but only because Scala is more concise.